# Integrating SEO with react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am working on a React js project and i got a task to integrate SEO with this project. I tried to get some open source and step by step process of integrating seo and how to plug in tags and end points but i didnt found any references. can any one please help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by implementing SEO ? Crawlers understand React so as long as you update titles and descriptions on route change in componentWillMount and implement include keyword you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [react helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet). You can add head tags on your component.

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing! So, **React** on its own can't solve this, hence it is always rendered on the client-side (SPA style), and search crawlers can't see any useful HTML, because the server sends back only a minimal HTML with a `app-root` component and a bunch of JS and the application/page is rendered somewhat later after the JS loaded.

To solve this you would need to apply Server Side Rendering - **SSR** in short.

I highly recommend [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/), which is production-ready framework built on top of React. It pre-renders all the pages on the server side by default with zero config.